# How to Create Scrollbar for a ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I am using **silverlight** and coding in c# and i have to create a scrollbar on a list displayed.

Currently the list is displayed without scrollbar but it should contain one scrollbar as well.

My code to display the List is:

```
ListBox lines = new ListBox(); 
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();            
scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
lines.ItemsSource = param.Component.Attributes.Items;
Grid.SetColumn(lines, 1);
Grid.SetRow(lines, LoopCount);
childGrid.Children.Add(lines);

lines.SelectedIndex = 0;
lines.SelectedItem = param.Component.Attributes.Items;
lines.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(List_SelectionChanged);
lines.SelectedIndex = lines.Items.Count - 1;
```

"lines" variable contains my ListBox and i tried to achieve it throught `scrollViewer` **but i dont know how to proceed further.**
(Please note that i have to create selection changed event on selecting the items on GUI displayed on button click) so the code for scrollbar must not influence that procedure. And i have to code in c# only not in xaml. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are puttig items Inside **ScrollViewer** You need to set the **Content** of ScrollViewer to ListBox,

change your code like below,

```
//Create ScrollViewer which is a child of Grid
var scroll = new ScrollViewer();
//add to the grid
childGrid.Children.Add(scroll);
//create lisbox and set it to the content of scrollviewer which is a Child of ScrollViewer
var listBox = new ListBox();
scroll.Content = listBox;
```

Comment: and then you print the scroll bar or list ? but why you first do this childGrid.Children.Add(scroll); and after that do this scroll.Content = listBox;   shouldnt we do it viceversa ?

Comment: Any ways the logic is correct so please edit it so that i will mark it as answer. Thanks

Comment: @user234839 Whats there to edit? everything is already described! the reason why i am adding scroll bar is that, listbox is a child control of scrollbar, scrollbar is a child control of grid.

Comment: but you add scroll in childGrid first and then you assign the contents of listbox.

Comment: I have done like this it is working(Is my approach to do so correct ?):            ListBox lines = new ListBox(); 
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();            
            scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
            lines.ItemsSource = param.Component.Attributes.Items;
            scrollViewer.Content = lines; 
            Grid.SetColumn(scrollViewer, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(scrollViewer, LoopCount);
            childGrid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);

Comment: @user234839 Yes, from the top to bottom approach, if you design in XAML, what you do? you create  a grid and then add scrollviewer and then set the listbox inside, same way its explained here.